# Image won't show up in css, works with position:relative

Tags: html, css, image, position, z-index

I recently changed all of my elements to `position: absolute` because they were all relative before, and now my background image won't show up (or do the animation).

```css
#firstbody {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 20;
}

#h1first {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
  margin: 200px 0px 0px 120px;
  padding: 0px 200px 0px 100px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica; 
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px white;
  white-space: nowrap
}
#firstbox {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px 300px 0px 30px;
  width: 500px;
  top: 300px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 200px;
  font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica;
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 20px; 
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px white;
}
#maincontent {
  margin:40px 180px 0px 180px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(110, 255, 175, 0);
  /*box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px grey; */
  border-radius: 15px;
}
#background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  animation-name: slidein; 
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  z-index: 50;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {top: -2000px;}
  100% {top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="firstbody">
            <div id="whitetransparency">
                
                <img id="background" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Pleyur/pleyur.github.io/main/topbackground.jpg" alt="topbackgroundimage">
            </div>
        </div> 
</body>
```

I took out #first body in the html and it worked, but I don't know why it doesn't work when I add it. Is it something to do with the position?

```
#firstbody {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: `width` of image is `100%` but parents `width` is `0px`. So `100%` of `0` is still `0`. Element which are `absolute` are always trying to be as small as they can until you specify some proportions attribute.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem. :D